# After Upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 can no longer access video files on CD/DVD

Tags: video, dvd

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 and can now no longer play non-audio CD/DVDs. Any clues on how to get this access back?

I can access discs some with VLC Media Player but not all.

In some instances Nautilus only shows audio (.wav) files even though there are other files on the disc. I can view all the files under Windows running as a virtual guest but can't see them native.